# TestNG. can't run a single test method

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, selenium-webdriver

I have Selenium+Eclipse+Java Project+Eclipse TestNG plugin.
For example, my code is:

```
public class TestClass {

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    ...
    }

//@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    ...
    }
```

When i run TestClass as TestNG, both tests are executed. 
I can't understand why test2 is executed also.
Because there is a comment "//" before @Test annotations.

Any ideas?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should clean the class files, then compile the project again